# Enumerar resultados en laravel 5.4

Tags: sql, laravel

Me podrían ayudar con este caso ? Vi que de esta forma se realiza pero me sal el error que adjunto así que no se que estoy haciendo mal /:

```
public function  index()
{

    // Inicializa @rownum

    DB::statement(DB::raw('SET @rownum = 0'));

    // Realiza la consulta

    $tops = DB::table('articles')
            ->select(DB::raw('id','head','description', '@rownum := @rownum + 1 as rownum'))
            ->where('approve', '=', 'Aprobado')
            ->where('important','Destacado')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->paginate(5);
    return view('index',compact('tops'));
}
```

Ahora tengo que el problema al ejecutar la consulta me sulta esto:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$head (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\IndieSonico\resources\views\index.blade.php)

De esta forma la estoy llamando en mi vista:

```
@foreach($tops as $top)


    <div id="tops0" class="card" style="border:none !important; margin: 0;">
        <a href="{{ route('show',$top->id.$top->head) }}">
            <img  class="card-img-top" src="../images/{{$top->path}}" alt="Card image cap" style="height: 112px">
        </a>
        <a href="{{ route('show',$top->id.$top->head) }}" class="a-corregido2">
            <span id="">{{$top->rownum}}</span><span class="title-tops">{{ $top ->head }}</span>
        </a>
    </div>


@endforeach
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Edita la pregunta y muestra el metodo del controlador donde llamas a la vista

Comment: Listo Samir Llorente

Comment: bueno no si no te has fijado pero tienes separado en la vista esta parte `{{ $top ->head }}` donde deberia quedar `{{ $top->head }}`

Comment: Ya lo corregí y me sigue saliendo lo mismo /: , estoy llamando bien el rownum ??

Comment: He si, hay algo pero mejor toma una captura al error

Comment: Listo, ya agregue la captura

Comment: bueno aun no estoy seguro, indicame cual es la linea 21 de tu codigo y que tratas de lograr aqui `<a href="{{ route('show',$top->id.$top->head) }}">`

Comment: Esta es mi linea 21:

@foreach($tops as $top)

Y lo que intento solo es agregar el head a la url y ya

Comment: Al parecer el error esta en la consulta, prueba poniendo `DD($tops)` antes del return a ver que datos arroja y prueba tambien poniendo `->get()` al final de la consulta

Comment: Collection {#637 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => {#630 ▼
      +"id": 20
    }
    1 => {#631 ▼
      +"id": 19
    }
    2 => {#632 ▼
      +"id": 18
    }
    3 => {#633 ▼
      +"id": 17
    }
    4 => {#634 ▼
      +"id": 15
    }
    5 => {#635 ▼
      +"id": 12
    }
  ]
}

Comment: ->select('id','head','description',DB::raw( '@rownum := @rownum + 1 as rownum')) tu consulta deberia quedar asi

Comment: Grandeeeeeeee! ya corre, muchas gracias !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque la respuesta ya esta dada en los comentarios, la pondre aqui para que otras personas pueden ver mas facilmente.

La consulta deberia ser:

```
->select('id','head','description',DB::raw('@rownum := @rownum + 1 as rownum'))
```

Dado que como esta en el problema se comete el error de ingresar las columnas a mostrar dentro del `DB::raw()`